# Big MySQL table, REPLACE -> very slow query

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a table with 17.6 million rows in a MyISAM database.

I want to searh an article number in it, but the result can not depend on special chars as dot,comma and others.

I'm using a query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table`
 WHERE 
 replace(replace(replace( replace( `haystack` , ' ', '' ),
 '/', '' ), '-', '' ), '.', '' )
 LIKE 'needle'
```

This method is very-very slow. `table` has an index on `haystack`, but `EXPLAIN` shows query can not use that, That means query must scan 17.6 million rows - in 3.8 sec.

Query runs in a page multiple times (10-15x), so the page loads extremly slow.

What should i do? Is it a bad idea to use replace inside the query?

Comment: Instead of providing us pseudo queries it might be best to show us the exact code and explain its purpose.

Comment: Also; why on earth does the query need to run that many times on a single page load?!

Comment: So your article numbers _might_ have dots, commas etc. in them? Then I’d use a second column, that contains the article number _stripped_ of those characters, for searching – that has only to be filled _once_ (for the existing rows via UPDATE, for new records at the time they get INSERTed), and can maybe even use an index (depending on what exactly you compare it to with LIKE).

Comment: That's nearly the exact code, just replaced the table and field names.
The page is a spare parts catalogue, so it MUST run multiple times, when i display a list of articles, and a list of alternatives for every article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do the replace on the actual data in the table, MySQL can't use the index, as it doesn't have any indexed data of the result of the replace which it needs to compare to the `needle`.

That said, if your replace settings are static, it might be a good idea to denormalize the data and to add a new column like `haystack_search` which contains the data with all the replaces applied. This column could be filled during an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. An index on this column can then effectively be used.

Note that you probably want to use `%` in your `LIKE` query as else it is effectively the same as a normal equal comparison. Now, if you use a searchterm like `%needle%` (that is with a variable start), MySQL again can't use the index and falls back to a table scan as it only can use the index if it sees a fixed start of the search term, i.e. something like `needle%`.

So in the end, you might end up having to tune your database engine so that it can held the table in memory. Another alternative with MyISAM tables (or with MySQL 5.6 and up also with InnoDB tables) is to use a [fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) index on your data which again allows rather efficient searching.

Comment: Copied normalized data to a new column, and got a much faster query - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `LENGTH` on the column, not sure if it gives a better affect. Also, when using `LIKE` you should use the `%`

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE 
haystack LIKE 'needle%' AND
LENGTH(haystack) - LENGTH(REPLACE(haystack,'/','')) = 0 AND
LENGTH(haystack) - LENGTH(REPLACE(haystack,'-','')) = 0 AND
LENGTH(haystack) - LENGTH(REPLACE(haystack,'.','')) = 0;
```

If the haystack is exactly needle then do this

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE 
haystack='needle';
```

Comment: if `haystack='needle'` then there's no need to do the length and replace checks...

Comment: Wow, that was pretty Obvious...oh well, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's "bad" to apply functions to the column as it will force a scan of the column.

Perhaps this is a better method:

```
SELECT list
     , of
     , relevant
     , columns
     , only
FROM   your_table
WHERE  haystack LIKE 'two[ /-.]needles'
```

In this scenario we are searching for "two needles", where the space between the words could be any of the character within the square brackets i.e. "two needles", "two/needles", "two-needles" or "two.needles".